# Robot controller uploaded but not working properly

Tags: ros, robotics

I have design a robot in ROS urdf, uploaded controller but it is not working as needed. Below are the files:
URDF File(mrm.urdf):

````
<robot name="mrm">
    <link name="world"/>
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value=" 1024.0"/>
            <inertia ixx="170.667" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                iyy="170.667" iyz="0"
                izz="170.667"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world"/>
        <child link="base_link"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="joint_1" type="revolute">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="link_1"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.5"/>
        <limit effort="1000" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5" />
    </joint>
    <link name="link_1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.4" length="0.35"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.4" length="0.35"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
            <mass value="157.633"/>
            <inertia ixx="13.235" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                iyy="13.235" iyz="0"
                izz="9.655"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <joint name="joint_2" type="revolute">
        <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
        <parent link="link_1"/>
        <child link="link_2"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.4"/>
        <limit effort="1000" lower="0" upper="0.5" velocity="0.5" />
    </joint>

    <link name="link_2">
        <inertial>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4"/>
            <mass value="57.906"/>
            <inertia ixx="12.679" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                iyy="12.679" iyz="0"
                izz="0.651"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.8" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.8" />
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4"/>
        </collision>
    </link>

<transmission name ="trans_1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_1">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor_1">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<transmission name ="trans_2">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_2">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor_2">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so"/>
</gazebo>

</robot>```

Config file(effort.yaml):
````

joint_1_controller:
type: "effort_controllers/JointPositionController"
joint: joint_1
pid: {p: 700.0, i: 50.0, d: 70.0}
joint_2_controller:
type: "effort_controllers/JointPositionController"
joint: joint_2
pid: {p: 700.0, i: 50.0, d: 70.0}

```
Launch file(effort.launch):
```

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find mrm_desp)src/urdf/mrm.urdf"/>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch" />

<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model mrm_desp"    />


<rosparam  file="$(find mrm_desp)src/config/effort.yaml"/>

<node name="Controller_Spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="joint_1_controller joint_2_controller" />
```

```

I am not getting where I did the mistake. Can someone help?